# Singularities from topological viewpoint

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, singularity-theory

I intuitively understand that 
\begin{align}
f:(-\infty.0)\cup(0,+\infty) &\to \mathbb{R} \\
x &\mapsto \dfrac{1}{x}
\end{align}
is "*singular*" at $x=0$, however, **is there a topological description of singularities**, in terms of say open sets? Or does one need to discuss singularities in the context of differentiable manifolds?

Comment: $f$ is just nothing at $x=0$, since it doesn't live there.

Comment: I don't remember a definition of a singularity. Concering a topological specific of $f$ at $0$ we may note that for each neighborhood $U$ of $0$ the function $f$ is unbounded on $U\cap\operatorname{dom} f$.

Comment: Topologically $f$ is the same as $g:(-1,0)\cup(0,1)\to(-1,0)\cup(0,1)\subset (-1,1)$ defined by $g(x)=x$, and $g$ is quite a nice function from a space to itself.